# Rotate any circle to have a flat top (aligned with the X axis)

Tags: mesh, vertices

So, back in older versions of blender it would generate circles with a flat top (aligned with the x axis) not with the point at the top (see image) [image]

I would like to know how to get that old behavior back, say a script or a setting it just gets a bit annoying at times for what im doing (low poly art)

Comment: I wonder whether  a GN circle would do? Then you could just copy it around, set the copies to point-up, or side-up, change the number of sides and radius, all in the modifier settings.

Comment: RZ90, then CTRL - A > Rotation to apply the rotation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Blender 3.1 (possibly earlier) and later, it appears that circles (actually regular N-gons) are generated with a vertex at $(0, radius)$. If you are aligning to *World*.

To rotate the circle so that a side is parallel to the axis, use the formula $R = 180 / N$ where $N$ is the number of vertices in the circle.  For instances, if you had a 6 sided "circle", $R = 180 / 6 = 30$.  Rotate the circle on the Z axis by this amount. This is because a regular N-Gon divides the 360 degrees of a circle into N segments with the same angle, $360/N$ but you only want to rotate half that angle to go from vertex on top to parallel edge on top.

If you do this in *Object* mode, be sure to apply the rotation after.  Here is a shortcut for a six sided object: <kbd>R</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd><kbd>6</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd>–<kbd>A</kbd><kbd>R</kbd>  Replace the <kbd>6</kbd><kbd>0</kbd> by the value of Z appropriate for the number of sides you specified when creating the circle.

This shortcut rotates (<kbd>R</kbd>) on the Z axis (<kbd>Z</kbd>) by 60 degrees (<kbd>6</kbd><kbd>0</kbd>) and accepts the rotation (<kbd>Enter</kbd>) Then it applies (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>–<kbd>A</kbd>) rotation (<kbd>R</kbd>).

If you accidently create a circle with a different alignment, say to view, or with the 3D cursor not at the origin, but you want your circle to be at the origin and on the XY plane, here's a shortcut to do that: <kbd>Alt</kbd>–<kbd>R</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd>–<kbd>G</kbd>.

This short cut resets first the rotation (<kbd>Alt</kbd>–<kbd>R</kbd>) and then the location (<kbd>Alt</kbd>–<kbd>G</kbd>).

Answer (score 2):

You to mess with these parameters when you add the circle.
[image]

Comment: Maybe I should improve my answer, I meant make the circle look like this by default: https://i.imgur.com/R8VjV3V.png